# Has this number-theoretic constant been studied?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Unless I made a mistake, the expected value of the largest exponent in the prime factorization of random positive integer (defined in the appropriate way) is $$\eta := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(1-\zeta(n)^{-1}\Big)$$ with the convention $\zeta(1)^{-1} = 0$ (for aesthetics). I was just wondering whether this constant $\eta$ has a name, whether it's been studied, etc..

Comment: What do you mean by “random positive integer”?

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte For $n \ge 2$, let $g(n)$ denote the/a largest exponent in the prime factorization of $n$. Then $\eta = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{n=2}^{N} g(n)$.

Comment: Ok, but I wouldn’t call this limit that way.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte I guess my last comment provided the definition for "largest exponent in prime factorization of a random positive integer" rather than for "a random positive integer" which is undefined.

Comment: (and since some more characters are needed, I add these ones)

Comment: Don't you mean to set $\zeta(1)^{-1}=-12$? (Joke, joke! Put down the pitchforks...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You're thinking of $\zeta(-1)^{-1}=-12$ (down, pitchforks, down). I may have just accidentally explained the joke.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you calculate it to a few decimals, you find
$$
1.705211140105\ldots
$$
which is enough to locate it in the OEIS.

It's Niven's constant: [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NivensConstant.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_constant), [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A033150).

As [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422356/has-this-number-theoretic-constant-been-studied#comment1085332_422366) by GH from MO in the comments, it was in fact proven by Niven in 1969 that the average largest exponent tends to $\eta$.

Since the question is essentially about finding literature related to a given numerical constant, I should probably mention [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263890/finding-a-closed-form-for-constant/4265349#4265349) by myself on the other site, exhibiting some other methods (Steven Finch's book *Mathematical Constants* & how to google the decimals effectively).

Comment: The OP's $\eta$ is Niven's constant. The OP's term corresponding to $n=1$ equals $1$. More importantly, it seems that the OP rediscovered Niven's theorem from 1969 (https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2037055).

Comment: Thanks! You just added a new tool to my toolbox: I've been using inverse symbolic calculators instead of inputting the digits as a sequence to the OEIS! Also, as GH said, $1$ must be added.

Comment: Glad if it helps! BTW you can input it into OEIS either as a sequence of digits ("7,0,5,2,1,1,1") or more conveniently as the decimal (".7052111"). I didn't know the latter one works until I tried it today.

Comment: GH, thanks, somehow I misread the first term as zero. Will fix that in my answer.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen It would be weird if the average of the largest exponent were less than $1$ :)

Comment: It is just me that thinks it's weird that OEIS contains digit sequences?

Comment: @Kimball, I always felt it weird as well, but perhaps that just indicates our unstated assumptions of what "is" an integer sequence. Formally digit sequences are integer sequences all right, and pragmatically it is at least a possible way of making them available. It is not perfect for that purpose, so if someone would like to set up a good database of numerical noninteger constants, that would be most welcome.